# How can I apply Payment Charge as %, For CCAVENUE MCPG to Customer

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, payment-gateway, payment-banktransfer

I have installed ccavenue mcpg for payment gateway, how can i apply payment charge for every transaction.

Comment: YOU CAN ADD CUSTOM ADDITIONAL FEES FOR EVERY ORDER .

Comment: how can i do that

Comment: You have to add extra fees or additional amount in payment gateway.. ??

Comment: Bro, just want to know that, how can i do that ??

Comment: okay, am waiting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48383/discussion-between-jeeva-rathinam-and-lalit-mohan).

Comment: Try this one https://magecomp.com/magento-payment-fee.html

Answer (score 2):

[image]
**Lalit_Fee/app/etc/modules/Lalit_Fee.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Lalit_Fee>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Sales />
            </depends>
        </Lalit_Fee>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**Lalit-Fee/app/code/local/Lalit/Fee/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/Create/Totals/Fee.php**

```
class Lalit_Fee_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Create_Totals_Fee extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Totals_Default
{
    /**
     * Use your own template if necessary
     * See "sales/order/create/totals/default.phtml" for model
     */
    // protected $_template = 'fee/sales/order/create/totals/fee.phtml';
}
```

**Lalit-Fee/app/code/local/Lalit/Fee/Block/Checkout/Totals/Fee.php**

```
class Lalit_Fee_Block_Checkout_Totals_Fee extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Total_Default
{
    /**
     * Use your own template if necessary
     * See "checkout/total/default.phtml" for model
     */
    // protected $_template = 'fee/checkout/total/fee.phtml';
}
```

**Lalit-Fee/app/code/local/Lalit/Fee/Block/Sales/Order/Totals/Fee.php**

```
class Lalit_Fee_Block_Sales_Order_Fee extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{

    /**
     * Get order store object
     *
     * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Order
     */
    public function getOrder()
    {
        return $this->getParentBlock()->getOrder();
    }

    /**
     * Get totals source object
     *
     * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Order
     */
    public function getSource()
    {
        return $this->getParentBlock()->getSource();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize fee totals
     *
     * @return Lalit_Fee_Block_Sales_Order_Fee
     */
    public function initTotals()
    {
        if ((float) $this->getOrder()->getBaseFeeAmount()) {
            $source = $this->getSource();
            $value  = $source->getFeeAmount();

            $this->getParentBlock()->addTotal(new Varien_Object(array(
                'code'   => 'fee',
                'strong' => false,
                'label'  => Mage::helper('fee')->__('Fee'),
                'value'  => $value
            )));
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

**Lalit-Fee/app/code/local/Lalit/Fee/etc/config.xml**

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Lalit_Fee>
            <version>0.1.5</version>
        </Lalit_Fee>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <sales>
            <quote>
                <totals>
                    <fee>
                        <class>fee/sales_quote_address_total_fee</class>
                        <renderer>fee/checkout_totals_fee</renderer>
                        <admin_renderer>fee/adminhtml_sales_order_create_totals_fee</admin_renderer>
                    </fee>
                </totals>
            </quote>
            <order_invoice>
                <totals>
                    <fee>
                        <class>fee/sales_order_total_invoice_fee</class>
                    </fee>
                </totals>
            </order_invoice>
            <order_creditmemo>
                <totals>
                    <fee>
                        <class>fee/sales_order_total_creditmemo_fee</class>
                    </fee>
                </totals>
            </order_creditmemo>
        </sales>
        <events>
            <paypal_prepare_line_items>
                <observers>
                    <paypal_prepare_line_items>
                        <class>fee/observer</class>
                        <method>updatePaypalTotal</method>
                    </paypal_prepare_line_items>
                </observers>
            </paypal_prepare_line_items>
            <sales_order_invoice_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <sales_order_invoice_save_after>
                        <class>fee/observer</class>
                        <method>invoiceSaveAfter</method>
                    </sales_order_invoice_save_after>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_invoice_save_after>
            <sales_order_creditmemo_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <sales_order_creditmemo_save_after>
                        <class>fee/observer</class>
                        <method>creditmemoSaveAfter</method>
                    </sales_order_creditmemo_save_after>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_creditmemo_save_after>
        </events>
        <fieldsets>
            <sales_convert_quote_address>
                <fee_amount>
                    <to_order>*</to_order>
                </fee_amount>
                <base_fee_amount>
                    <to_order>*</to_order>
                </base_fee_amount>
            </sales_convert_quote_address>
        </fieldsets>
        <pdf>
            <totals>
                <fee translate="title">
                    <title>Fee</title>
                    <source_field>fee_amount</source_field>
                    <font_size>7</font_size>
                    <display_zero>0</display_zero>
                    <sort_order>650</sort_order>
                    <amount_prefix></amount_prefix>
                </fee>
            </totals>
        </pdf>
        <resources>
            <fee_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Lalit_Fee</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </fee_setup>
        </resources>
        <models>
            <fee>
                <class>Lalit_Fee_Model</class>
            </fee>
        </models>
        <blocks>
            <fee>
                <class>Lalit_Fee_Block</class>
            </fee>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <fee>
                <class>Lalit_Fee_Helper</class>
            </fee>
        </helpers>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <fee>
                    <file>fee.xml</file>
                </fee>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <fee>
                    <file>fee.xml</file>
                </fee>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
    <default>
        <sales>
            <totals_sort>
                <fee>15</fee>
            </totals_sort>
        </sales>
    </default>
</config>
```

**Lalit-Fee/app/code/local/Lalit/Fee/etc/system.xml**

```
<config>
    <tabs>
        <lalit translate="label" module="fee">
            <label>Lalit</label>
            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
        </lalit>
    </tabs>
    <sections>
        <lalit translate="label" module="fee">
            <label>Fee Options</label>
            <tab>lalit</tab>
            <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <groups>
                <lalit_group translate="label" module="fee">
                    <label>Fee Options</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <lalit_input translate="label">
                            <label>Value: </label>
                            <comment>Amount that will added as fee</comment>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </lalit_input>

                    </fields>
                </lalit_group>
            </groups>
        </lalit>
    </sections>
</config>
```

**Lalit-Fee/Lalit-Fee/app/code/local/Lalit/Fee/Model/Observer.php**

```
class Lalit_Fee_Model_Observer
{

    /**
     * Set fee amount invoiced to the order
     *
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     * @return Lalit_Fee_Model_Observer
     */
    public function invoiceSaveAfter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $invoice = $observer->getEvent()->getInvoice();

        if ($invoice->getBaseFeeAmount()) {
            $order = $invoice->getOrder();
            $order->setFeeAmountInvoiced($order->getFeeAmountInvoiced() + $invoice->getFeeAmount());
            $order->setBaseFeeAmountInvoiced($order->getBaseFeeAmountInvoiced() + $invoice->getBaseFeeAmount());
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set fee amount refunded to the order
     *
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     * @return Lalit_Fee_Model_Observer
     */
    public function creditmemoSaveAfter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $creditmemo = $observer->getEvent()->getCreditmemo();

        if ($creditmemo->getFeeAmount()) {
            $order = $creditmemo->getOrder();
            $order->setFeeAmountRefunded($order->getFeeAmountRefunded() + $creditmemo->getFeeAmount());
            $order->setBaseFeeAmountRefunded($order->getBaseFeeAmountRefunded() + $creditmemo->getBaseFeeAmount());
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Update PayPal Total
     *
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     * @return Lalit_Fee_Model_Observer
     */
    public function updatePaypalTotal(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $cart = $observer->getEvent()->getPaypalCart();

        $cart->updateTotal(Mage_Paypal_Model_Cart::TOTAL_SUBTOTAL, $cart->getSalesEntity()->getFeeAmount());

        return $this;
    }

}
```

**Lalit-Fee/app/code/local/Lalit/Fee/sql/fee_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php**

```
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$installer->run("
    ALTER TABLE  `".$this->getTable('sales/order')."` ADD  `fee_amount` DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE  `".$this->getTable('sales/order')."` ADD  `base_fee_amount` DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) NOT NULL;
");

$installer->endSetup();
```

**Lalit-Fee/Lalit-Fee/app/code/local/Lalit/Fee/Model/Fee.php**

```
class Lalit_Fee_Model_Fee extends Varien_Object
{

    /**
     * Fee Amount
     *
     * @var int
     */
    const FEE_AMOUNT = 20;

    /**
     * Retrieve Fee Amount
     *
     * @static
     * @return int
     */
    public static function getFee()
    {
        return self::FEE_AMOUNT;
    }

    /**
     * Check if fee can be apply
     *
     * @static
     * @param Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function canApply($address)
    {
        // Put here your business logic to check if fee should be applied or not

        // Example of data retrieved :
        // $address->getShippingMethod(); > flatrate_flatrate
        // $address->getQuote()->getPayment()->getMethod(); > checkmo
        // $address->getCountryId(); > US
        // $address->getQuote()->getCouponCode(); > COUPONCODE

        return true;
    }

}
```

**Lalit-Fee/app/code/local/Lalit/Fee/Model/Sales/Quote/Address/Total/Fee.php**

```
class Lalit_Fee_Model_Sales_Quote_Address_Total_Fee extends Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract
{

    protected $_code = 'fee';

    /**
     * Collect fee address amount
     *
     * @param Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address
     * @return Lalit_Fee_Model_Sales_Quote_Address_Total_Fee
     */
    public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
    {
        parent::collect($address);

        $this->_setAmount(0);
        $this->_setBaseAmount(0);

        $items = $this->_getAddressItems($address);
        if (!count($items)) {
            return $this;
        }

        $quote = $address->getQuote();

        if (Lalit_Fee_Model_Fee::canApply($address)) {
            $exist_amount = $quote->getFeeAmount();
            $fee = Lalit_Fee_Model_Fee::getFee();
            $balance = $fee*0.01 - $exist_amount;

            $address->setFeeAmount($balance);
            $address->setBaseFeeAmount($balance);

            $quote->setFeeAmount($balance);

            $address->setGrandTotal($address->getGrandTotal() - $address->getFeeAmount());
            $address->setBaseGrandTotal($address->getBaseGrandTotal() - $address->getBaseFeeAmount());
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add fee information to address
     *
     * @param Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address
     * @return Lalit_Fee_Model_Sales_Quote_Address_Total_Fee
     */
    public function fetch(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
    {
        $amount = $address->getFeeAmount();
        $address->addTotal(array(
            'code' => $this->getCode(),
            'title' => Mage::helper('fee')->__('Fee'),
            'value' => $amount
        ));
        return $this;
    }

}
```

**Lalit-Fee/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/fee.xml**

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <adminhtml_sales_order_view>
        <reference name="order_totals">
            <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_totals_item" name="fee" template="fee/sales/order/total.phtml" />
            <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_totals_item" name="fee.refunded" template="fee/sales/order/refunded.phtml">
                <action method="setDisplayArea"><area>footer</area></action>
                <action method="setAfterCondition"><condition>last</condition></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_sales_order_view>

    <adminhtml_sales_order_invoice_new>
        <reference name="invoice_totals">
            <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_totals_item" name="fee" template="fee/sales/order/total.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_sales_order_invoice_new>

    <adminhtml_sales_order_invoice_updateqty>
        <reference name="invoice_totals">
            <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_totals_item" name="fee" template="fee/sales/order/total.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_sales_order_invoice_updateqty>

    <adminhtml_sales_order_invoice_view>
        <reference name="invoice_totals">
            <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_totals_item" name="fee" template="fee/sales/order/total.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_sales_order_invoice_view>

    <adminhtml_sales_order_creditmemo_new>
        <reference name="creditmemo_totals">
            <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_totals_item" name="fee" template="fee/sales/order/total.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_sales_order_creditmemo_new>

    <adminhtml_sales_order_creditmemo_updateqty>
        <reference name="creditmemo_totals">
            <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_totals_item" name="fee" template="fee/sales/order/total.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_sales_order_creditmemo_updateqty>

    <adminhtml_sales_order_creditmemo_view>
        <reference name="creditmemo_totals">
            <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_totals_item" name="fee.refunded" template="fee/sales/order/refunded.phtml">
                <action method="setDisplayArea"><area>footer</area></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_sales_order_creditmemo_view>
</layout>
```

**Lalit-Fee/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/fee.xml**

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <adminhtml_sales_order_view>
        <reference name="order_totals">
            <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_totals_item" name="fee" template="fee/sales/order/total.phtml" />
            <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_totals_item" name="fee.refunded" template="fee/sales/order/refunded.phtml">
                <action method="setDisplayArea"><area>footer</area></action>
                <action method="setAfterCondition"><condition>last</condition></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_sales_order_view>

    <adminhtml_sales_order_invoice_new>
        <reference name="invoice_totals">
            <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_totals_item" name="fee" template="fee/sales/order/total.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_sales_order_invoice_new>

    <adminhtml_sales_order_invoice_updateqty>
        <reference name="invoice_totals">
            <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_totals_item" name="fee" template="fee/sales/order/total.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_sales_order_invoice_updateqty>

    <adminhtml_sales_order_invoice_view>
        <reference name="invoice_totals">
            <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_totals_item" name="fee" template="fee/sales/order/total.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_sales_order_invoice_view>

    <adminhtml_sales_order_creditmemo_new>
        <reference name="creditmemo_totals">
            <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_totals_item" name="fee" template="fee/sales/order/total.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_sales_order_creditmemo_new>

    <adminhtml_sales_order_creditmemo_updateqty>
        <reference name="creditmemo_totals">
            <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_totals_item" name="fee" template="fee/sales/order/total.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_sales_order_creditmemo_updateqty>

    <adminhtml_sales_order_creditmemo_view>
        <reference name="creditmemo_totals">
            <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_totals_item" name="fee.refunded" template="fee/sales/order/refunded.phtml">
                <action method="setDisplayArea"><area>footer</area></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_sales_order_creditmemo_view>
</layout>
```