# Custom discount to customer in admin order create by percentage without coupon code?

Tags: magento-1.8, discount

Task:  I need to give option in back-end admin order create page to sale executive so they can provide % discount(text box)  to user when create order for them..

what I ask in this question but this is little bit different what I tried.. 
[How to add custom extra discount(%) to order or override default coupon code when placed from back end only?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/145783/how-to-add-extra-discount-to-quote-when-order-create-from-back-end-only)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I apply Payment Charge as %, For CCAVENUE MCPG to Customer](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/145432/how-can-i-apply-payment-charge-as-for-ccavenue-mcpg-to-customer)

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara  My question is little bit different . percentage discount box in admin order create page.. then get instant discount not shown in frontend

Comment: is solved your issue?

Comment: @lalitmohan Is your issue solved?